# TFS 2018 Update 2 RC. Slow perfomance in Web

Tags: tfs

we have an on premises TFS 2018 Server with Update 2 RC.

The perfomance of the web is very slow. We work with kanban and scrum boards and it take a few seconds to load, furthermore, moving a task to one column to another can take a few seconds

The operating system is Windows 2016 Server. 16GB RAM, and 4 processors of 2.6ghz. It´s a virtual machine. It has been working propertly until the last month.

I have checked and changed:

The elastic search extension has been deactivated because it takes more than 5GB of memory

The antivirus has been disabled.

The processor is below 15% and the memory is around 50%

IIS Worker Process is taking 1.2GB of RAM

I have deleted the "TfsData\ApplicationTier_fileCache" with no success

We are out of ideas, any help would be really appreciated.

Thanks in advance

[image]

Comment: If CPU and memory utilization are low, then the problem **isn't** the application tier. What about your data tier?

Comment: Any clue to check the data tier? SQL Server only consumes 116MB

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's difficult to know what's going on there with this information, an approach to let you perform a best analysis could be the typical divide an conquer approach, in your case:

- Put the Agent in other machine.
- Install the TFS and MsSql Server in different machines, you can try a clean install of TFS using your current MsSql.

Once you did this you will:
 - Have a more stable system.
 - Be able to analyze which part is creating problems.

Comment: Thanks for the help. It seems that the issue is related with the bad perfomance of the hard disk of the virtual machine. We are working on solving this

Comment: You are welcome, I am happy to know that helps you to identify the problem.